# How do I initialize a long-lived class in a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I have an `Api` class that accepts an (optional) authentication `token` that it uses for making authenticated requests e.g. `Api(token: 'a9sa2ksas12').getUserDetails()`.

If the token is not passed, it has to perform the relatively expensive operation of reading it from `sharedPreferences`.

```
class Api {
  static const BASEURL = "https://api.google.com/";
  final String token;

  Api({ this.token });

  Future<http.response> getUserDetails() async {
    return http.get('$BASEURL/user/', headers: { 'Authorization': token });
  }
}
```

How can I setup my app so that the token is read only once from `sharedPreferences` and used throughout the app for all future `Api()` requests?

Some ideas I've considered and think that may work:

- Have `token` be a global variable
- Make the API class a singleton, and pass it around between "screens"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the "Locator" pattern, via [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it).

The code was pretty simple.

#### Step 1: Setup a top-level `locator.dart` in `lib/`

```
// ./lib/locator.dart
import 'package:my_app/services/api.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;

void setupLocator() {
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => Api());
}
```

#### Step 2: Use `api` anywhere in the app by just importing the locator:

```
// ./lib/widgets/some_screen.dart
class _SomeScreenState extends State<SomeScreen> {
  Api api = locator<Api>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    api.getUserDetails().then((response) => {
      // do anything you like with the response
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

The beauty of this approach is that `Api` is only ever initialized ONCE in the lifetime of the app, so I simply assign a `token` to it on `initState` without worrying about the widget getting disposed/rebuilt and repeated fetches to SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 3):

Well in general there's nothing bad in making you `Repositories` a singletons. But on the other hand, I don't like the concept of passing the `API` classs between the screens.

When `widgets` use your data source directly without any middleman, like `Bloc` or `Provider`, they tend to be polluted with a lot of presentation logic. I personally prefer to separate those concerns and let widgets do what they are made for: rendering the UI. This makes them smaller and easier to test.

What's more the `API` class should be responsible only for the network calls. It shouldn't be responsible for managing the token. I'd inject to the `API` class something like:

```
class TokenProvider 
{
   Future<String> getToken();
}
```

The responsibility of this class would be, you guessed it, to provide a token. It can return cached value or get it from the `SharedPreferences`. Thanks to this the `API` doesn't have to care where the token comes and how to handle it. It will do just one thing: api calls.

Comment: Thanks. And how can I make the TokenProvider persist across screens?

Comment: If you not going to do some refactoring you should inject `TokenProvider` into the `Api` class and pass the `Api` singeltone accross the app.

Comment: I'd like to refactor, but am unsure how. Would the `TokenProvider` need to have it's own widget that wraps the App in `main.dart` and does the `sharedPreferences` fetch once, followed by successive API calls made using `Api(token: TokenProvider.of(context).token)` in the various screens?